# How to setup Parse live query with Android (Java) with self-hosted server URL

Tags: java, android-studio, parse-platform, parse-live-query

I'm trying to use Parse live queries in Android Studio following [this back4app guide](https://www.back4app.com/docs/android/live-query). I enabled live query and set up the LiveQuery client following Steps 1 and 2 in the guide. However, I am having trouble with Step 3 (subscribing to the query). Here's what I tried:

```
// Back4App's Parse setup
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
    .applicationId(APPLICATION_ID)
    .clientKey(CLIENT_KEY)
    .server("wss://<my_subdomain>.back4app.io/").build()
);
// Init Live Query Client
ParseLiveQueryClient parseLiveQueryClient = null;
        
try {
    parseLiveQueryClient = ParseLiveQueryClient.Factory.getClient(new URI("wss://<my_subdomain>.back4app.io/"));
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

replacing the application id, client key, and subdomain appropriately. But this resulted in an error: `java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: wss` and I was unable to create the Parse application. I tried replacing `wss://` with `https://` in the server URL. The application ran, but every Parse SDK request returned `error: unauthorized`. Before changing the server URL, I had been using `"https://parseapi.back4app.com"` and everything worked perfectly. I'm unsure how to fix this issue - any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The guide looks wrong. Could you please try with https in the first url and wss in the second one?